# Combine 3 VBA codes and run it as a single piece of code

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 VBA codes that do the same actions on 3 different sheets. I want to run all 3 codes as a single code.

I did it like this but it gives

> application error (Error 1004)

```
Sub lastRow()
    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
    Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
    Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long

    Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru Input")
    Set wsS2 = Sheets("Final Input")
    Set wsS3 = Sheets("FinalInputFile")

    With wsS1
        lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
    End With

    With wsS2
        lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)
    End With

    with wsS1
        lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
    End With

    With wsS3
        lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
        .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your autofill method seems to be wrong correct example is `Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2") 
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20") 
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange` Secondly compiler giving problem on the code line `.Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)`

Comment: the code works fine if i run it separately for each sheet

Comment: Note that **all** your `Range` have to start with a dot like `.Range` otherwise they don't make use of the `With` statement. Some of your `Range` are missing the dot.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show code for one sheet only in addition to existing code which is working for that sheet to help in debugging the problem. It is giving error of Autofill method failed.

Comment: What is the line at which you are getting the error? Did you look @Pᴇʜ's suggestion on using `.Range`?

Comment: In Excel 2010 Autofill works in a single direction only, either horizontal or vertical. Therefore, if you wish to fill a 2-dimensional range you should first fill one row horizontally (including the source cell) and then use that row as source copy the entire row down. Please check your Excel Version also.

Comment: @Peh I have checked the code after putting dot before Range , even then Autofill method of Range Class Fails.

Comment: error 1004 got solved but now i am getting "Autofill method of range class failed" error is what i am getting

Comment: @peh you're suggestion worked thanks :)

Comment: Autofill is filling the range but code gives the error

Comment: @j.doe Just curious to know what main change corrected the program to work correctly.

Comment: @skkakkar I assume that the OP has the line after `AutoFill` in the same line as `AutoFill` so `.Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)` is the destination parameter for `Autofill` otherwise that all doesn't make any sense. So that it is 2 lines in the question is just a formatting issue I think. • I posted it as an answer.

Comment: @PEH Thanks for clarifying the matter. I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that all your `Range` have to start with a dot like `.Range` otherwise they don't make use of the `With` statement. Some of your `Range` are missing the dot.

So instead of

```
With wsS2
    lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)
End With
```

it should be

```
With wsS2
    lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill .Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)
End With
```